# Transform to Riemann sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How could this expression be turned into a Riemann sum to be calculated?

$$\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n\cos(i/m)\rfloor} \frac{\sin(i/m)}{mn}\right)$$

Presumably, I should set $i=x$ and $j=y$, and calculate it as a double integral, but what to do about the $m$ and $n$ in the denominators?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where did you see this sum? Why do you suppose it has an integral form? Etc... also, please check my edit - I tidied up your mathjax and made some guesses as to what you meant but I may have not represented the original question you meant to ask

Comment: Thank you. I made a small edit as well (i instead of j in the sin function).
It is one of a number of practice exercises for a course. The task is to transform and calculate it, so it should have an integral form.

Comment: I notice that the summand does not depend on $j$... this is strange

Comment: First of all even in the single variable/summation case , you do not set $i=x$ . If $f$ is Riemann integrable then you can say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\frac{i}{n})=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$

Comment: Show that the sum is bounded between $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \cos(i/m) \sin(i/m) $ and $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \cos(i/m) \sin(i/m)+ \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \sin(i/m)$

Comment: Thanks all. Trying to get a grip on what you said..

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Could you explain the purpose of the $\frac{1}{n}$ outside of the sum?

Comment: @Bronze Not to be rude or anything, but should you really be trying to solve Riemann sums if you do not know the justifications behind it?. Maybe this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods. You should try and search for maybe some youtube videos online that explains this in a non-rigourous intuitive manner. Otherwise the proper theory behind it is called Riemann integration and it would require some knowledge of real analysis to dive into.